# HTML Parser to Get Content between Elements

Tags: php, parsing

I'm looking to parse data out of about 100 pages, all of which have this string of HTML in it:

```
<span class="cell CellFullWidth"><span class="SectionHeader">EVENT</span><br/><div class="Center">Event Name</div></span>
```

I'm not very familiar with parsers, so I'm wondering what I should use to extract the "Event Name" from each page that I loop through, and how I should go about doing that.

I looked into Simple HTML DOM but I couldn't quite figure it out.
Please help, thanks!

Comment: Is all the text except "Event Name" always exactly the same?

Comment: Yes it is. The only thing that will change in the string I provided will be "Event Name". The span classes, and div class will always remain the same, though.

Comment: Are there more elements on the page with `class="Center"`?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming:

- All event names are in divs
- The containing div must have the class "Center"
- All divs with the class "Center" contains the name of an event

Here goes:

```
<?php

$content = '
<span class="cell CellFullWidth"><span class="SectionHeader">EVENT</span><br/><div class="Center">Event Name1</div></span>
<span class="cell CellFullWidth"><span class="SectionHeader">EVENT</span><br/><div class="Center">Event Name2</div></span>

';

$html = new DOMDocument();

$html->loadHTML($content);

$divs = $html->getElementsByTagName('div');

foreach($divs as $div) {
    if($div->getAttribute('class') == 'Center') {
        $events[] = $div->nodeValue;
    }
}

print_r($events);
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the text except the event name is always the same, you can do it with just a substring (since the start and end bits will always be the same length)

```
$event_name = substr($current_line, 98, -14);
```

That'll give you what's left over when you remove the first 98 characters and the last 14.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PHP's DOM manipulation functions](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Basically, you'd create a new DOMDocument via [DOMDocument::loadHTML()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) or [DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php)), and then use [$yourDOmObject->getElementsByTagName()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) to get all the `<span>` elements.